# Show there is a tower of cyclic field extensions of prime degree from $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{5})$ to $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, galois-extensions, normal-extension

Of course, it suffices to find tower of Galois extensions of prime degree, as these would have to be cyclic. My first thought was to try extending $\mathbb{Q}$ first by $\sqrt 5$, then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt 5)$ by $\sqrt[4]{5}$ and $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})$ by $\sqrt[12]{5}$, but then the last extension isn't Galois as it's not normal. I tried extending $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{5})$ by $\omega_3\sqrt[12]{5}$ where $\omega_3$ denotes the third root of the unit, but of course this gives me a different field at the top of the tower, not $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[12]{5})$. In general, I'm clueless on how to find a Galois extension of degree three which doesn't have imaginary numbers.

Comment: I don't see how this approach could hope to work because $\Bbb Q (\sqrt[12] 5)$ isn't Galois over $\Bbb Q$.

Comment: @Robert Shore so is there no such a tower of extensions? If $L_1\subset L_2\subset...\subset L_n$ is a tower such that $L_{k+1}/L_k$ is Galois, must $L_n/L_1$ be Galois? If such is the case I think the exercise wouldn't be possible, as a cyclic extension is necessarily Galois...

Comment: It is contained in a tower of cyclic extensions but it is not itself a tower of cyclic extensions (need to add $\zeta_3$). One can show that every subfield is of the form $\Bbb{Q}(5^{1/n})$ with $n|12$.